# Python: "yield from " produces syntax error

Tags: python

I'm using the [Gaston Frequent Subgraph Mining implementation by Njissen](https://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/~nijssensgr/gaston/)  on Ubuntu 16.04 and tried it both on Python 3.6.5 and 2.7.15rc1. When executing the program I get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elias/.local/bin/gaston", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gaston-py==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'gaston')()
  File "/home/elias/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 484, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/elias/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2725, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/elias/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2343, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/elias/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2349, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/elias/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gaston_py/gaston.py", line 5, in <module>
    import gaston_py.factory as factory
  File "/home/elias/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gaston_py/factory.py", line 7, in <module>
    import gaston_py.embedding as embedding
  File "/home/elias/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gaston_py/embedding.py", line 70
    yield from _create_embedding_list(graph, visited, neighbor_id)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

in

```
yield from _create_embedding_list(graph, visited, neighbor_id)
```

Code block that produces the error:

```
def _create_embedding_list(graph, visited, node_id):
    for edge_label, neighbor_label, neighbor_id in sorted(_neighbor_labels(graph, visited, node_id)):
        if (node_id, neighbor_id) not in visited:
            visited.add((node_id, neighbor_id))
            visited.add((neighbor_id, node_id)) # if graph is undirected

            yield node_id, (edge_label, neighbor_label)
            yield from _create_embedding_list(graph, visited, neighbor_id)
```

Since this is the official implementation I suspect incompatibilities or similar. How do I get this code running? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Please post the *full* error, including at least the line and position indicator. Note that your pasted code has the ``for`` incorrectly indented - fixing this makes the code raise no error on Python 3.7.0.

Comment: The indentation is clearly wrong. Please [edit] your question to not only remove the obvious syntax errors, but also to make sure the code you post is *exactly* the code you are having problems with.

Comment: Note that ``yield from`` is a python3 only construct. Your traceback is from python2. Please post a traceback from python3.

Comment: How do you run this program? Do you call ``gaston``, ``/home/elias/.local/bin/gaston``, or ``python3 /home/elias/.local/bin/gaston``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I call the program with `gaston`

Comment: Try running it as ``python3 $(which gaston)``, or it will always use python2.

Comment: The error is now _DistributionNotFound_ `File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 778, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'gaston-py==0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application`. Thanks, it uses now Python3. Now I have to figure how to find the gaston-py distribution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the traceback shows, you are running this code in Python 2.7. But `yield from` was introduced in Python 3 3 and is not supported on earlier versions.

Comment: The answer mentions he tried it also on Python 3.6.5, but has not shown the traceback.

Comment: I set an alias so python will call python3, but it still uses python 2.7. The user does not call python, but apparently a C++ script does. How do I force to use Python3.x?

Comment: I have no idea, you will need to post some details of how the C++ script calls Python.

Comment: After taking a look at the C++ code, unfortunately, I cannot tell how the C++ code compiles into Python2.7. Cntr+F the project files for python (and similar) did not find any results. For installation I strictly followed the README and simply ran make and then gaston